# Using ng-repeat with bootstrap css and span tags for error message

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using Angular Js, in which I am using bootstrap css. I have a ng-repeat added to the form. I have a submit button at the end of page. I have added a required field validation to each of the controls being created in ng-repeat. On click of submit button, if the data is not available in any of the rows in ng-repeat, I am showing a error message. This works fine. However, if there are 20 rows in ng-repeat, and if all are left empty, clicking on submit button is dragging the page, thereby the submit button becomes invisible. I have used the below code:

```
 <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<body class="ng-cloak">
<div ng-controller="testController" ng-init="init()">
<form name="mainForm" id="createForm" ng-submit="mainForm.$valid && add()" novalidate="">
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="Descriptions in seasonsWithDescription ">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2 top-Margin-language">
                        <label ng-model="Descriptions.Language">{{Descriptions.Language}}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4 top-Margin-Title">
                        <input type="text" maxlength="150" class="form-control input-md" required="" name="titleValidate_{{$index}}" ng-model="Descriptions.Title" />
                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.titleValidate_{{$index}}.$error.required">Title is required</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                        <textarea maxlength="500" class="form-control input-md noresize" required="" name="descriptionValidate_{{$index}}" noresize="" ng-model="Descriptions.Description"></textarea>
                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.descriptionValidate_{{$index}}.$error.required">Description is required</span>
                    </div>


                    <br />
                </div>
<br/>
   <div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-6">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submitted=true" /> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Adding screenshot to explain in more:
[image: Initial Page load]

[image: After error message]

As you can see, the buttons are getting invisible when the error messages are shown. Is this the correct way to use css and span in ng-repeat.  I have tried with setting

```
style="min-height:100px;"
```

in the form, but that did not solve it. How to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: please give plunker of your code and css.

Comment: I am creating the plunker for first time. Not sure, if what i have done is correct -  http://plnkr.co/edit/eotknyBr4nTpBY9aRvwk?p=preview

Comment: Add your code i mean script in plunker else it is not going to useful

Comment: HI. sorry for that. I have updated in here http://plnkr.co/edit/eotknyBr4nTpBY9aRvwk?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It could work, but it's much more complicated than it needs to be. Check out angular forms (link below)

```
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <textarea name="descriptionValidate_{{$index}}" class="form-control input-md noresize" required="" maxlength="500" ng-model="Descriptions.Description" noresize=""></textarea>
    <span style="color: red;" ng-show="submitted == true && mainForm.descriptionValidate_{{$index}}.$error.required">Description is required</span>
</div>
```

It will turn into (styling excluded)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required>
</div>
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

There are a number of validation rules built into an Angular input
required

- ng-required="{ boolean }"
- ng-minlength="{ number }"
- ng-maxlength="{ number }"
- ng-pattern="{ string }"
- ng-change="{ string }">

More on input validation usages: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input

Hopefully this helps simplify some of your code